# redirect to another action in same controller with paramters

Tags: redirect

> i want to pass parameter from one action to another in same controller
>   how to do that

**also how the other function receive(how to get it ) parameters??**

```
$parameters =array('user_id'=>5,'name'=>'test');
is $this->_forward('edit',NULL,NULL,$parameters); correct or what is the correct way ??
```

and if it is correct how to get parameters in edit action

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes your code seem correct

```
$parameters =array('user_id'=>5,'name'=>'test');
$this->_forward('edit',NULL,NULL,$parameters);


public function editAction()
{
    $user_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
    $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
```